# Regression with constrained output variable

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions

I want to predict the labels of images using a neural network.
The labels all lie in the range [-1,1] (Ratio scaled).
Values with an absolute value greater than one are meaningless and do not occur in the data.

How do I design the final layer? What loss function should I use?

My approach is a "tanh" activation, to squeeze the output into [-1,1] and 'MSE' as the loss function. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I design the final layer? What loss function should I use?

The final layer should fit to the desired output, in your case oyu should predict a value between: [-1,1]

Here is an overview about the activation functions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function

> My approach is a "tanh" activation, to squeeze the output into [-1,1], Does that make sense?

tanh is fine for that approach. which is also quite common is: Softsign

Comment: Thanks. I was asking this also because I have only seen the usage of tanh, sigmoid and so forth to predict probabilities for classification. I thought maybe it is only applicable for this special case.